# Angular 2 - Add data to a nested json with HTTP Post requset

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular2-http

I have a JSON file with this structure:

```
let data = [
      {
        item: '1',
        details:
          [
            {name: 'name1', address: 'address1'},
            {name: 'name2', address: 'address2'},
            {name: 'name3', address: 'address3'}
          ]
      },
      {
        item: '2',
        details:
          [
            {name: 'name1', address: 'address1'},
            {name: 'name2', address: 'address2'},
            {name: 'name3', address: 'address3'}
          ]
      }
    ];
```

I want to add nested JSON object (child).
For example, to add another entry to the details of "Item1", like this:

```
      item: '1',
      details:
      [
          {Name: "name1", address: 'address1 "},
          {Name: "name2", address: "address2"},
          {Name: 'name3', address: 'address3'},
        **{Name: 'name4', address: 'address4'}**
      ]
```

How can I do this using HTTP Post request?
(JSON file is local, and I use "InMemoryBackendService")

Comment: Are you trying to mock a service? If so, is this for development or for unit testing? If it is for development, instead of Http, you can just create the observable on your own, using Observable.from([data]), after writing to the file (find a good file system package).

Once you have your service set up, you can implement Http (assuming that's what you want to do).

Comment: @scottmgerstl, Thanks for the comment!
Actually, my main problem is adding a nested JSON object (child).
I mean, how to add new "detail" to a specific item?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Which version of javascript are you writing in? ES5, ES6, or Typescript

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing in Typescript:

```
public addDetail(itemId: string, detailToAdd: any): void {
    data.find(i => i.item === itemId).details.push(detailToAdd);
}
```

This is represented in ES5 as

```
function addDetail(itemId, detailToAdd) {
    data.find(function (i) { return i.item === itemId; }).details.push(detailToAdd);
}
```